How many Akira Toriyama mangas have animated series?
As far as I know, the mangas from Akira Toriyama which got animated are Dr Slump, Dragon Ball and Sand Land. But I remember seeing 1 or 2 shorts animes more from him, one which had a Freezer-looking character, and another which had a Trunks-looking character (or were the 2 of them in the same anime? I can't remember). But I know there are more mangas from him like Jaco or Pink. So,
How many Akira Toriyama mangas have animated series?

Not sure if it is exhaustive, but this Wikipedia page lists animes based on Akira Toriyama's stories, which include (except Dr SLUMP and Dragon Ball)

Go! Go! Ackman
小助さま力丸さま -コンペイ島の竜- (OVA)
剣之介さま (20 mins short movie)
貯金戦士キャッシュマン
PINK


Strange they dont mention Dragon Ball

@Pablo I just didn't include them. Just put the lesser knowns.
